# Remove 'nan' from Dictionary of list

Tags: python, pandas, list

My data contain columns with empty rows that are read by pandas as `nan`.
I want to create a dictionary of list from this data. However, some list contains `nan` and I want to remove it.

If I use `dropna()` in `data.dropna().to_dict(orient='list')`, this will remove all the rows that contains at least one `nan`, thefore I lose data.

```
Col1 Col2  Col3
a     x     r
b     y     v
c           x
            z



data = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[2], sep = ',')
dict = data.to_dict(orient='list')

Current output:
dict = {Col1: ['a','b','c',nan], Col2: ['x', 'y',nan,nan], Col3: ['r', 'v', 'x', 'z']}

Desire Output:
dict = {Col1: ['a','b','c'], Col2: ['x', 'y'], Col3: ['r', 'v', 'x', 'z']}
```

My goal: get the dictionary of a list, with `nan` remove from the list.

Comment: Can you show sample input/expected data?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly the format you're expecting, but you can use list comprehension and itertuples to do this.

First create some data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Col1': (1, 2, 3), 'Col2': (4, 5, 6), 'Col3': (7, 8, np.nan)})
print(data)
```

Giving a data frame of:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     1     4   7.0
1     2     5   8.0
2     3     6   NaN
```

And then we create the dictionary using the iterator.

```
dict_1 = {x[0]: [y for y in x[1:] if not pd.isna(y)] for x in data.itertuples(index=True) }

print(dict_1)
>>>{0: [1, 4, 7.0], 1: [2, 5, 8.0], 2: [3, 6]}
```

To do the same for the columns is even easier:

```
dict_2 = {data[column].name: [y for y in data[column] if not pd.isna(y)] for column in data}

print(dict_2)
>>>{'Col1': [1, 2, 3], 'Col2': [4, 5, 6], 'Col3': [7.0, 8.0]}
```

Comment: This is nice, but I wish to use Columns name as a Keys

Comment: I've added how to do that too.

Comment: I think your answer only works with float? For some reasons I get 'TypeError: a float is required'

Comment: That's because I assumed your data was numeric and used math.isnan rather than pd.isna. The math version can only can take a limited number of data types. I've updated the answer, hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if I do and what you want is to replace the `nan` with a value so as not to lose your data then what you are looking for is [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function. You mentioned the original value is an empty row, so filling the `nan` with `data.fillna('')` which fills it with empty string.

**EDIT**: After providing the desired output, the answer to your question changes a bit. What you'll need to do is to use [dict comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension) with list comprehension to build said dictionary, looping by column and filtering `nan`. I see that Andrew already provided the code to do this in his answer so have a look there.

Comment: This will create a list with ' ' values

Comment: Yes, I thought that was what you desired as, at the time of writing this answer, there was no desired output specified. Will update my answer accordingly.